# Forums for discussions?

Tags: discussion

A lot of my questions would be better answered in a discussion rather that Q&A style, and although I love the answers I get here, it often ends up being discussion anyways due to the way I ask the questions, and I don't want to keep accidentally bending the rules here. For **pathfinder related** questions where it's hard to keep it clear, or when it's really a series of questions, but they all have to do with one another - where could I ask those?

Alternatively are there resources to / where can I learn to get better at forming really clear questions?

Comment: Fyi, you can also ask questions like that in our chat - though it won't be the same as a large discussion board.

Comment: Some of this depends on what you want to ask. If you want RAW stuff Paizo or Giant in the Playground may be good places to look, but if you want more game design-ish stuff (mechanics and balance) you may want to also consider sites that cater to more general game-design things.

Comment: Paizo.com forums.  Though I'm not sure this question is constructively formed either (at best a list q); meta might be a better place.

Comment: I never noticed chat nor meta! Thanks for pointing it out. I'm still new here.

Comment: Wow... I'm in the meta! Everything is so black and white here - even the icon. ;-) 
Just checked out the FAQ - this place is a great idea! - I must say I'm really impressed with this whole stackexchange thing and excited to become a better/more concise writer of questions and answers :-)

Comment: I have a question about the meta itself - it says in the FAQ questions related to the role-play community - i.e. rpg.stackxchange... The pathfinder discussion I wanted to have is about coping with the risk of character death, etc. - which doesn't really have to do with the community itself. So it still wouldn't belong? But asking about a place where I can ask that question would belong here?

Comment: That's correct. For really off-topic or discussion-y things, chat (or a forum site) is the place to go. Sometimes a chat discussion ends up resulting in a solid question to post on the main site, too.

Comment: totally true. Didn't know of the meta, so I didn't see that earlier. Thanks for pointing it out. So do I delete this one now then?

Comment: @Julix there's no harm in letting it get closed as a dupe, if it is one. It might be more useful that way because then other people wondering about this will see the original thread and go "Oh, okay! great!" - compared to this being deleted, and those people just wondering what happened to it.

Comment: cool, thanks for the clarification.